# Windows Container (Nano Server) with ASP.NET Core

Tags: docker, windows, containers

I'm trying to make an Windows Nano Server container that runs an ASP.NET Core app.
 I'm building it on Windows Server 2016.  I can make it work, but there is one odd problem.

The only way I can make it work is to build the image, run the container, *then* start an interactive Powershell session and use `Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:5000`.  Once I do that, the app is visible from other servers (I can't browse the container locally from the Win2016 Server due to a known NAT bug.)

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk-nanoserver
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY /ContainerPOC/ .
RUN dotnet restore --runtime win10-x64 .

RUN dotnet build --framework netcoreapp1.1 --runtime win10-x64 .

EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://0.0.0.0:5000
CMD dotnet run --framework netcoreapp1.1
```

Any idea why this won't "just work?"

Comment: What's happening in the other ways?

Comment: If I don't do the Invoke-WebRequest, the app doesn't respond to requests from outside.

Answer (score 1):

As it is unclear what command and subcommands you used to run the docker container it could be possible that you run the container without using the `-p` subcommand. In this case `docker run -p 5000:5000 <image_name>` could solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need run entrypoint like as:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.1
...

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "netcoreApp.dll"]
```